# TCP_NODELAY not found on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, sockets, setsockopt

I am trying to disable the **Nagle's Algorithm** with my TCP sockets on an Ubuntu Linux box by setting the `TCP_NODELAY` parameter.  For some reason, this constant is not defined in `<sys/types.h>` or `<sys/socket.h>`.  Has this constant been deprecated and then removed from Linux or am I just missing something?

```
bool Socket::setTCPNoDelay(bool enabled)
{

    int flag = (enabled ? 1 : 0);

    if(setsockopt(m_sock,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Did you `#include <netinet/tcp.h>`?